# Tmdb::InvalidApiKeyError (Tmdb::InvalidApiKeyError)

Tags: etl, themoviedb-api, kiba-etl

When I am using Kiba ELT, I have followed the tutorials in YouTube as well as the tutorials provided by the owner. Yet, I am getting this error:

```
bitlasoft@Bitlasoft-TS-22:~/test01$ bundle exec kiba movies.etl
{
    "title: Blade Runner" => "title: Minority Report"
}
/home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/themoviedb-1.0.1/lib/themoviedb/api.rb:37:in `set_response': Tmdb::InvalidApiKeyError (Tmdb::InvalidApiKeyError)
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/themoviedb-1.0.1/lib/themoviedb/search.rb:75:in `fetch_response'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/themoviedb-1.0.1/lib/themoviedb/search.rb:60:in `fetch'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/themoviedb-1.0.1/lib/themoviedb/resource.rb:41:in `search'
    from /home/bitlasoft/test01/common.rb:30:in `process'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in process_rows'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:34:in `each'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in process_rows'
    from /home/bitlasoft/test01/common.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1739:in `each'
    from /home/bitlasoft/test01/common.rb:11:in `each'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:33:in `block in process_rows'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:32:in `each'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:32:in `process_rows'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/runner.rb:13:in `run'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/lib/kiba/cli.rb:13:in `run'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/kiba-0.6.1/bin/kiba:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/kiba:23:in `load'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/kiba:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/bitlasoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
bitlasoft@Bitlasoft-TS-22:~/test01$
```

Here is my movies.etl and common.rb config:

```
 require_relative 'common'
api_key = IO.read('.themoviedb')
source CSVSource, filename: 'movies.csv'        
limit ENV['LIMIT']
show_me!
transform MovieDBlookup,
api_key: api_key,
title_field: 'title'
show_me!
```

```
require 'csv'
 require 'awesome_print'

 class CSVSource 
    def initialize(filename:)   
    @filename = filename
        end

  def each
    csv = CSV.open(@filename, headers: true)
    csv.each do |row|
    yield(row.to_hash)

    end 

csv.close

    end
        end 

  require 'themoviedb'

class MovieDBlookup
 def initialize(api_key:, title_field:)
 @title_field = title_field
 Tmdb::Api.key(api_key)
    end

 def process(row)
 movie = Tmdb::Movie.find(row[@title_field]).first
 row[:vote_average] = movie.vote_average
 row[:vote_count] = movie.vote_count
 row
    end 
    end

def show_me!    
    transform do |row|
    ap row
    row
    end 
    end

def limit(x)
x = Integer(x || -1)
return if x == -1
   transform do |row|
   @counter ||= 0 
   @counter += 1
   abort("stopping....")if @counter >= x
   row
    end 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

(Kiba owner here) - the error you get isn't Kiba specific ; it looks like the API key you provided for [themoviedb](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb) is invalid. Did you sign-up for the movie db [here](https://www.themoviedb.org/account/signup), and is the API key provided copy-pasted into the file you are loading (`.themoviedb`)?

One problem I could think of would be that you'd have a line ending character in that file (carriage return / line feed), in which case maybe just calling `api_key = IO.read('.themoviedb').strip` could help.

Again, this isn't Kiba specific, but hope this helps!